# Button в Java Swing. Как выполнить действие после нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, swing

Создал кнопку в диалоговом окне в Java через Swing.
Теперь нужно чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку выходило окно с сообщением.
Где-то видел, что можно сделать через if(если кнопка нажата) то {}.
Хотел бы узнать, какой именно синтаксис должен быть в скобках оператора if.

```java
Button b = new Button("Button");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b);

if(b.isSelected()){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text number1")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таких примеров на самом деле уйму в интернете, но окей. Вот пример создания слушателя

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
        });
```

При нажатии на кнопку `button` - в консоли пропишется `ОК`

P.S. Насколько я помню `Button` относится к библиотеке `AWT`, если вы хотите писать именно на `Swing`, рекомендую использовать `JButton`, и почему именно `Swing`? Новые программы сейчас на этой библиотеке не пишут, только поддерживаются старые, и то уже не часто встретишь их на сколько я знаю, попробуйте изучить хотя бы JavaFX

Comment: Влад, swing выбрал в образовательных целях, с FX знаком. Спасибо за ответ. Возможно ли Вам в лс задать пару вопросов?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan Помню что чат доступен с 20го рейтинга, но может зайти сможете - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95528/swing

Comment: может с Вами можно связаться через скайп или ВК? Чат недоступен

Comment: @ArturVartanyan напиши свои контакты, я свяжусь, скайп/вк/WhatsApp